# Is there a way to run Apps Script web applications in a "queue", respecting the completion of one execution to start the next?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

I have a web application that is started by my CRM, but sometimes it runs twice in a very short period of time and this is affecting the proper functioning of the code, causing 2 simultaneous executions to be carried out. Is there a way to do it like a queue? So that executions were not carried out at the same time, but instead respected the completion of one to begin the other?

I don't know if it's possible to do what I want but I tried searching here and didn't find anything, as it could have been an error in my research so I decided to open this question.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) to make the latter runtime instance wait until the previous one has completed.

See [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock).